# Freeform: How do you change a name of a form that you have cloned?

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, bug

I clone the form.

Click on the cloned form from the list.

Change handle.

Click into name field and start to type and the save button disappears.

Craft 3.4.02

Comment: Hi Eric, can I get some more information? Where are you in the CP that you are cloning these forms? Seems you're trying to duplicate an element and then save it? I'll need to try and duplicate what you're doing in order to help you out.

Comment: It appears to be resolved with a recent update. Was cloning from the list of forms. There is a clone button next the the delete button.